# Add optional parameter to function after a "params object[]" parameter

Tags: c#

There's a function I have in an API that a lot of other libraries use, but I want to adapt it for a new feature to take an added optional parameter. The method signature is:

```
protected Task EnvGetJsonAsync<TReceive>(string endpointName, params object[] pathArgs)
```

and I wanted to add "string key = null" after pathArgs, because I have 37 references to this function that are used to this format. So that I don't have to change all 37 references (Also most of the references don't need to the optional param) I just wanted to add an optional param at the end.

I tried changing "params object[]" to just "object[]" but it caused an error with all the references. So it looked like this

```
protected Task EnvGetJsonAsync<TReceive>(string endpointName, params object[] pathArgs, string id = null)
```

and then this

```
protected Task EnvGetJsonAsync<TReceive>(string endpointName, object[] pathArgs, string id = null)
```

but both caused issues. I want a way to allow the function to take on an optional param without breaking the other 37 references. Thank you!

Comment: You can't really do this. A params parameter must be the last parameter in the formal parameter list. However adding a parameter to method, even an optional one is a breaking change. Arguably it might be better to simply add a new method with a new name that takes the new parameter and then follows with an optional parameter list.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3948971/c-sharp-4-0-optional-parameters-and-params-do-not-work-together

Comment: Instead of using optional parameter, can you use method overload and create method: `protected Task EnvGetJsonAsync<TReceive>(string endpointName,  string id, param object[] pathArgs,)` instead. Internally it can both methods can call same private method and you would not break existing references.

Comment: @AnkitVijay While this is legal, I will note that this can cause a subtle change in behavior, depending on what the id parameter does in the method. Imagine I had `EnvGetJsonAsync<Type>("endpointname", 'path/arg")`. pathArgs is an array of one item. When I recompile with the new library, overload resolution selects a different method and id is "path/arg" and pathArgs is empty. If the id parameter is semantically different, a new method is probably warranted.

Comment: Hi @mjwills and Mike I  was writing faster than I was thinking. Thanks for correcting me :)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot have optional parameters after `params` as per the documentation:

> No additional parameters are permitted after the params keyword in a method declaration, and only one params keyword is permitted in a method declaration.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/params

You can put optional parameters *before* your `params`, however because your `params` array type is an `object` you'll probably run into run time errors selecting the wrong method if your first `pathArgs` type is a `string`.

The best way would be to add a new method with your optional parameter, using a slightly different name. Your reference methods can then use the appropriate method if they have the key or not. You can then call the new method from the old with a null or default value for key:

```
protected Task EnvGetJsonAsync<TReceive>(string endpointName, params object[] pathArgs)
{
    return EnvGetJsonWithKeyAsync<TReceive>(endpointName, null, pathArgs);
}

protected Task EnvGetJsonWithKeyAsync<TReceive>(string endpointName, string key, params object[] pathArgs)
{
    // your method here
}
```

Comment: `The best way would be to add a new method with your optional parameter` Great solution, with no risk to existing callers.

Answer (score 1):

You can move your optional parameter before `param`. As per [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/params)

> No additional parameters are permitted after the params keyword in a
>   method declaration, and only one params keyword is permitted in a
>   method declaration.

It is better to create new method for new input and based on input you can call your existing method from there.

Overloading will not be working for `param`. You will not get any compile time error. It will call the last method at run time. You can check this [fiddler](https://dotnetfiddle.net/twl364) for more.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a new method, move the implementation there and use the old one to call the new method. That way your 37 callers will never notice the change:

```
protected Task EnvGetJsonAsync<TReceive>(string endpointName, params object[] pathArgs)
{
  // this is the original method. Here we just call the new one
  return EnvGetJsonoAsync<TReceive>(endpointName, null, pathArgs);
}

protected Task EnvGetJsonAsync<TReceive>(string endpointName, string id, params object[] pathArgs) 
{
  .. the code implementation
}
```

Comment: `That way your 37 callers will never notice the change:` Unless they passed a string as their second parameter. ;)

Comment: You're right, sir! In that case, the overload resolution will prefer the second method. Thanks!